# count rows with if condition AWK

Tags: if-statement, awk, count

do you know where I have a problem? I would like to count values in $4 column for all rows, with condition, for this rows in first column must not be a chrY or chrX, others rows will be count.

```
 awk ' {if ($1 != "chrY" || $1 != "chrX") sum+=$4} END{print sum}' "$i"_pool018_2.tsv
```

Thank you.
Filip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($1 != "chrY" || $1 != "chrX")
```

should be

```
if ($1 != "chrY" && $1 != "chrX")
```

if you used logical or, if the first check is evaluated as `true`, the 2nd won't be checked. That is, all entries with `$1="chrX"` would be added into `sum` variable.

example:

```
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{x=5;if(x!=3||x!=5)print "OK"}' 
OK
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, you should paste input/output examples.